# How can I get the inverse of the transfer function $\Phi$? a question from Page 56 of Lemma 4.5 in the book "ESSENTIALS OF ROBUST CONTROL"

Tags: control-theory, mathematical-modeling, optimal-control, linear-control

Let $\Phi(s) = = \gamma^2 I + B^*\left( (sI-A)(C^*C)^{-1}(sI+A^*) \right)^{-1}B + B^*(sI+A^*)^{-1}C^*D - D^*C(sI-A)^{-1}B - D^*D.$
How to compute the inverse of $\Phi$, in Page 56 of Zhou's book "ESSENTIALS OF ROBUST CONTROL", the answer is directly given as follows
$\begin{bmatrix}
   R^{-1}D^*C & R^{-1}B^*
  \end{bmatrix} \left[\begin{matrix}
   sI-A-B R^{-1} D^* C & -B R^{-1} B^* \\
   C^*\left(I+D R^{-1} D^*\right) C & sI+\left(A+B R^{-1} D^* C\right)^*
  \end{matrix}\right]^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
   BR^{-1} \\
   -C^*DR^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix} + R^{-1}.$
with $R = \gamma^2 I - D^*D$.
How to obtain this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have that

$$
\Phi(s)=\gamma^2I-H^{\sim}(s)H(s)
$$
where $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$ and $H^\sim(s)=-B^*(sI+A^*)^{-1}C^*+D^*$. The state-space representation for $\Phi(s)$ is given by
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
A & 0 & B\\
-C^*C & -A^* & -C^*D\\
\hline
-D^*C & -B^* & R
\end{array}\right].
$$

Now, we use that the inverse of a system $(A,B,C,D)$ is given by $(A-BD^{-1}C,BD^{-1},-D^{-1}C, D^{-1})$

This yields the following state-space representation for $\Phi(s)^{-1}$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
A+BR^{-1}D^*C & BR^{-1}B^* & BR^{-1}\\
-C^*(I+DR^{-1}D^*)C & -(A+BR^{-1}D^*C)^* & -C^*DR^{-1}\\
\hline
R^{-1}D^*C & R^{-1}B^* & R^{-1}
\end{array}\right],
$$
from which the result follows.